# I want to make a batch file that copies *.inf files in hard disc to my pen drive on autorun?

Tags: batch-file

Today I was trying to create a batch file which up on execution, searches my d drive for inf files and copies them to my pen-drive files folder. I was trying this code:

```
for /r "d:\" %i in (*.inf) do copy /y  "%~fi" "\files"
```

How to put it in a batch file and automate it...

Answer (score 0):

Double the percent characters `%%` on `for` loop variables when in a batch script.

```
for /r "d:\" %%i in (*.inf) do copy /y "%%~fi" "\files"
```

---

#### Recommended for speed:

```
xcopy D:\*.inf "\files" /S /I /Y
```

**Note** The source and target drive cannot be the same for the xcopy method.

Or

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a-d/b/s D:\*.inf') do copy /y "%%~fA" "\files"
```